# How to restrict painting on a QGraphicsScene to a specific area?

Tags: qt5, qgraphicsscene, qtcharts

I have a a QChart with a QLineSeries. In order to add custom graphics elements to the chart I am using the chart's underlying QGraphicsScene and its relevant `add*` methods.

The problem is that the QGraphicsScene's area is larger than QChart's plotting area, thus the QGraphicsItems, added directly to the scene, could be painted outside of the plotting area. For example:

[image]

Here the vertical grey line is the chart's plotting area border, and the line series, managed by the chart, are clipped at this point, but the black lines, added directly to the scene, are painted outside the border.

I wonder, what would be the best approach to restrict painting for my custom elements to the chart's plotting area?

By saying *best* I mean:

- Easy to manage. This is a real-time chart with a bunch of custom graphics elements, being added and removed across time.
- Not affecting performance.

Am I supposed to add a transparent item (widget?) on top of the chart's plotting area (there is a `plotArea`property for a QChart, which, I assume, specifies it), enable `QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsChildrenToShape` and then use it as a parent for my custom elements?

Are there any other methods? With this one what I personally don't like is that you have +1 layer in the stack of QGraphicsItems. Not that it hurts me right now, but it probably can in the future, as you add more elements to the chart and then need to interact with them. Z-order, event propagation, all this stuff can become more complicated. And I prefer to keep it simple.

Comment: ```QChart``` is a ```QGraphicsWidget``` subclass. so just derive it in another class and call ```this->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsChildrenToShape,true);``` in its constructor or just call ```setFlag``` by your QChart

Comment: How exactly should this help? Do you mean implementing your own chart class? Because to use `QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsChildrenToShape` on existing QChart object you don't need to subclass it. I tried it, and it doesn't help. Even with this flag and custom elements being children of QChart, they are painted outside the plotting area. I looked at QChart source, and the geometry logic is not available through public API. So I guess you could build your own chart class and modify the geometry logic, but for me this is not an easy way to go (I work with Python and PyQt, not C++ directly).

Comment: in your custom elements, do you clip the painter?

Comment: For each individual element? No, I don't.